# How rewrite Objective-C Macro expand with swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

The Objective-C Macro is like:

```
#define CALL_FUNC(classname, times, classfuncWithParamter) \ 
{\
     for (int i = 0; i< times; i++) {\
          [classname classfuncWithParamter]\
     }\
}\
```

calling for Objective-C:

```
CALL_FUNC(AnClass, 10, setName:@"test" withPhone:12345)
```

What puzzles me is this for-loop call func, Macro can do text substitution to do this

What is the best way deal with this Macro in Swift?

Comment: Use closures. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: As Apple states here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift, there's no counterpart for macros like this in Swift. But as they say on the same page, "you can use functions and generics to achieve the same results without any compromises". But in order to provide any help with that, it's important to know how do you use this macro: what types of classes / functions are called with it. What is the use case - why do you need this macro at all...

Comment: In your case it is a function with to parameters : number of repeat, and Class.classMethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have stated in the comments, you'll need to use generics and closures. The trick is that you'll have to declare the "macro" multiple times if you want to support multiple numbers of parameters:

```
// for functions with no arguments
func call<T>(times: Int, _ f: () -> T) {
    for i in 0..<times {  f() }
}

// for functions with one argument
func call<A, T>(times: Int, _ f: (A) -> T, _ arg: A) {
    for i in 0..<times { f(arg) }
}

// for functions with two arguments
func call<A1, A2, T>(times: Int, f: (A1, A2) -> T, _ a1: A1, _ a2: A2) {
    for i in 0..<times { f(a1, a2) }
}

// for functions with three arguments
func call<A1, A2, A3, T>(times: Int, f: (A1, A2, A3) -> T, _ a1: A1, _ a2: A2, _ a3: A3) {
    for i in 0..<times { f(a1, a2, a3) }
}

// and so on...
```

For the sample from your question, the call would look something like this:

```swift
call(times: 10, AnClass.setName(_:withPhone:), "test", 12345)
```

, or you can pass a closure, and make the code more readable, like this:

```swift
call(times: 10) { AnClass.setName("test", withPhone: 12345) }
```

, and if you choose this road you can keep only the first `call` definition, the one without arguments: `func call<T>(_ times: Int, f: () -> T)`. Calling the desired function within a closure is also more flexible, as you can support any numbers of arguments within that closure.

Comment: I thank pass closure is the best way, thanks for you answer